# Running a powershell script from SQL Agent using CmdExec

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2, command-prompt, sql-agent

The following command runs perfectly fine directly from a command prompt (not PowerShell), however when i run it as a step in Job with type 'Operating system (cmdExec) it fails with the message 
"

> The process could not be created for step 1 of job  (reason: The
>   system cannot find the file specified).  The step failed."

Sql server version: 2008 R2

```
powershell -noexit "& ""D:\PS\abc.ps1"""
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That sounds like powershell.exe is not in the PATH. Have you tried explicitly providing the location? Perhaps `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Comment: That did it, thank you lit.